# Problem with requesting XML in Node.js from specific website

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with getting the xml from a get-request from this URL: https://feeds.meteoalarm.org/feeds/meteoalarm-legacy-atom-austria

In the browser, it all works fine, and also when I check the content on https://reqbin.com/, I get as a response a nice xml.

When I run my code, I just get a 404 status code back:

```
const request = require('request');
var urlAtom = 'https://feeds.meteoalarm.org/feeds/meteoalarm-legacy-atom-austria'
request.post({
        url:     urlAtom,
        timeout: 8000
      }, function(error, response, body){
        if (error){
              adapter.log.error(error)
            )
        }
        if (response.statusCode == 200){
            adapter.log.info('Status Code:' + response.statusCode)
        }
        else{
            adapter.log.warn('Status Code:' + response.statusCode)
        }
      });
```

I tried it with another URL, there I get a 200 status code, so it doesn't seem connected to my device. I am not sure if this server requests any special parameters or so (I already tried playing around with useragend). I would be happy about any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a GET request, So change request.post to request.get,

```
const request = require('request');
const urlAtom = 'https://feeds.meteoalarm.org/feeds/meteoalarm-legacy-atom-austria'
const adapter = { log: console }
request.get({
    url: urlAtom,
    timeout: 8000
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        adapter.log.error(error)
    }
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        adapter.log.info('Status Code:' + response.statusCode)
    }
    else {
        adapter.log.warn('Status Code:' + response.statusCode)
    }
});
```